Is Mathematics, The Only Original creation of Mind?
This question arose out of debate between heart and mind and the debate between heart and mind arose from content at Stack Exchange(Logic, Mathematics, Philosophy etc.). The content in these sites is Predominantly the product of Mind because everything is so formal, proper, follow rules sort of. It's hard to find heart in it. It does not mean it's heartless, but you get my point.
So I started thinking, is it that,  Logic->Math->Science the only original creation of mind? Of course heart is involved but doesn't it kinda feel Mind could have done on it's own.
But everything else, be it music, painting, dance, romance, poetry, whole of everything else basically, is a product of heart.

Mind: Cognitive entity that works with logic, rules, definitions, system, "formalising things".


Heart: Works with things other than those mentioned above.


I am not sure if you are including philosophy, but that the content on this site is "formal, proper, and follows rules" is not the impression I get a lot of the time. If "heart vs mind" is supposed to reflect rational vs emotional approaches then yes, mathematics, science and (analytic) philosophy are dominated by the former while arts by the latter. Theology and law combine both more equally.

If we had no mind, would dance/art/music/painting/poetry still exist in the same way? If not, then mind must be a prerequisite for those things, if not necessarily a dominant component.

@controlgroup hey hay see you cannot treat this discussion technically that way because see, you cannot function without mind but also you cannot "devote" to anything without heart either, so both are required ALWAYS, but it's like if you were thinking hypothetically if there is some topic that Mind came up with exclusively on it's own, wouldn't it be Logic, because everything in Nature including Nature itself, studies itself AND ONLY ITSELF....

A computer can prove mathematical formulae though, and obviously has no heart. Thus math and logic do not require heart. "Heartless" i.e. completely-non-sapient organisms can also do computations in the same way silicon chips can. Perhaps a more rigorous definition of mind and heart are in order.

The seemingly extremely axiomatized foundational nature of math perhaps intrigues your mind into imagine a highrise tower creative building process while other areas lack or too flexible to become a safe tall tower, since it's a strict step-by-step process upon which you seem can go higher and higher grasping more knowledge. But if that highrise metaphoric image is wrong, then your seemingly intuitive and popular conclusion could be wrong too...

@controlgroup EXACTLY!!!!! My Point. See Computer can solve "Mathematical Formulae"  but Computer cannot "Formulate" anything Original, "Intuitive". I have observed when you start discussing fundamentals of logic where domain of Language and Logic merge then ChatGPT starts going around in circles and doesn't give intuitive answers. It's answers feel intuitive upto certain depth but AT THE VERY FUNDAMENTALS LEVELS they are mere repetition of "known", nothing intuitive. So yes, for definition, COMPUTER = MIND, EVERYTHING ELSE = HEART....

@DoubleKnot I am NOT AT ALL WORRIED about my assumption being "could be wrong", I AM REALLY INTERESTED in Knowing Whether my assumption "COULD BE CORRECT"!?!!!!!

Notice there's no tower becoming higher and higher in computers. When it's unexamined, whether popular or not, is hard to be confident to be correct...

@DoubleKnot I am not very eager to reach a  conclusion yet but really to more ponder over it. See I feel you are approaching it from "Knowledge", I am stading WITH Heart and Mind, irrespective of "Knowledge" aspect of it but looking at World at large and if I were to decide who(Heart/Mind)  should be credited for "Inventing" WHAT???!!!! Then rather than worrying about "Defining" and "Verifying", because these two things are so INTIMATELY INTERTWINED that it will be an whole endeaver but more Generally, Naturally, does the question seems meaningful?!!!!..

Image is critical for both mind and emotion, right? So if the formed image in your mind is wrong, it could be blamed instead of either heart or mind...

@DoubleKnot I think you are discussing something else other than the immediate  question. It's about whether everything mind does can be abstracted to a very small set....

Too broad. What does to create means in this context? Raising up new ideas? Physical things? In addition, you assume "the mind" and "the heart" create different contents, which is weird. The heart just pumps blood.

@RodolfoAP Neither is Mind Physical nor Heart(in this context).

Spoken or signed language, an original creation of mind, would have to precede both the study of logic and mathematics.

Formal logic and formal mathematics, need language, yes. But other animals have demonstrated that they can count at least to some extent, and it is hard to argue that an animal solving a puzzle is not applying at least basic logic. Of course, this leads into the question of what constitutes "mind"...

Ok ya didn't think about languages, but I have been thinking about Language for past few days though. Languages are something that "Happened" to Mind, it wasn't a product of conscious effort towards it. See origin of language and it's records and  recorded age are two completely different things.

Language is not a creation of the mind. Language is the evolved form of natural interactions, like sexual interchange, aggressiveness, attraction, rejection, etc. For example, first, animals evolved the expression of aggression behaviors with specific sounds (roaring, hissing, growling). Now, humans do the same, but with words ("I will SMASH your head!"). Both cases are just language.

@keshlam Other animals don't study logic or mathematics. That would require language far beyond a few spontaneously generated vocalizations (e.g. barks, grunts or chirps), probably a written language.

The question didn't explicitly say formal or higher or whatever; it could easily be fixed to do so.
